# Yii2 rendering view doesn't work correctly

Tags: php, yii2

I have 3 tables:

- Order
- Ordered_number
- Number

**Ordered_number** connects the other two - it has order_id and number_id columns.

In my Index Action, I want to render view named "call", where I have a form with choosing one order. When I submit which order I want, I want to go to actionCall and send there numbers connected with this order. Something isn't correct and I think I may be doing something wrong.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new \common\models\Order();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        $numery = \common\models\Number::find()
                ->joinWith('ordered_number')
                ->where(['ordered_number.order_id' => $model->id]);
        return $this->redirect(['/call', 'numery' => $numery]);
    } else {
        $this->render('call', ['model' => $model]);
    }
}
```

When I open my actionIndex it displays a blank page instead of rendering a view that I want.

My "call" view:

```
    <?php

use common\models\Customer;
use common\models\Order;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\web\View;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

/* @var $this View */
/* @var $form ActiveForm */
/* @var $model Order */

var_dump($this);
die();

echo "<h1>Dodaj numery do przedzwonienia</h1>";
echo "Wybierz zamówienie, którego numery chcesz przedzwonić: ";

$form = ActiveForm::begin();
$form->field($model, 'id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(Customer::find()->all(), 'id', 'id'));
Html::submitButton("Przedzwoń", ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']);
ActiveForm::end();
```

I added var_dump in my view, and it displays it, but without var_dump and die() command, there is simply blank page without text I want to be next.

Comment: update your question and show you call view code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing `return` statement in `else`

```
return $this->render('call', ['model' => $model]);
```